# Separate string for document javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

This would be my first post on this page and I would like to get help as I don't know how to do a function and I might need some ideas ...

In summary, I have a String, and I want to find if that string contains a word like "Dog", and that separates it from the String and creates an HTML element where the word will be ... In case you didn't understand me, here I pass an example of the result that I expect

```
// String
let string = "Hello, I have a sofa, and a pet that would be a dog. Although I like cats better"

//Code
<markdown>
     Hello, I have a sofa, and a pet that would be a <span class = "animal"> dog </span>. Although I like cats better
</markdown>
```

Comment: Is the "Dog" the only value that you want to replace? Or It can contain more values as well?

Comment: Yep. The only thing that I have no idea how to do it is to separate the dog from the String, I have tried with `.replace`, but the span is shown in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ty usng `String.prototype.replace()` with regex.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let string = "Hello, I have a sofa, and a pet that would be a dog. Although I like cats better";
function replaceDOM(str, word) {
    var regEx = new RegExp(word, "ig");
    const newStr = string.replace(regEx, `<span class = "animal">${word}</span>`);
    console.log(newStr);
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = newStr;
}
replaceDOM(string, "Dog")
```

```html
<p id="placeholder"></p>
```

If your DOM elements are being created dynamically, you can refer the solution below.

```js
let string = "Hello, I have a sofa, and a pet that would be a dog. Although I like cats better";
function replaceDOM(str, word) {
    var regEx = new RegExp(word, "ig");
    const newStr = string.replace(regEx, `<span class = "animal">${word}</span>`);
    const pTag = document.createElement('P');
    pTag.setAttribute('id', 'placeholder');
    pTag.innerHTML = newStr;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(pTag);
}
replaceDOM(string, "Dog");
```

Comment: Something particular that happens to me with this method is that it does not find the id of the tag, `document.getElementById (" ")`, it returns null even if I have put an ID to the markdown

Comment: @RayG. Since this function is getting called when the page loads, make sure that you are adding the script tage below the body, this ensures that script is executed after body is loaded. If you use script tag above the body, script executes before body is loaded.

Comment: And there is no way to do it with everything done in js? I do not know if I understood what I said, but the whole page is made based on `document.createElement ()`, `document.append`, I have tried to put id with` -.setAtribute ("id", "ThisIsMyID"), but it does not detect it in the .js file, what I come to is that if there is no way to do that before the page loads

Comment: @RayG. I have updated the answer. Plase check, hope that will really help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to search for your key word. Then store in a variable. The use JS or JQuery to create a new html element with your string inside of it and create another html element with your found word inside of it. Then combine them.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do it? pls

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much [@Nitheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099327/nitheesh), your code helped guide me. Although I had to make some modifications ... Here I pass the resulting code in case someone has the same doubt

```js
let string = "Hello, I have a sofa, and a pet that would be a dog. Although I like cats better";
function replaceDOM(str, word, tag) {
    var regEx = new RegExp(word, "ig");
    const newStr = string.replace(regEx, `<span class = "animal">${word}</span>`);
    tag.innerHTML = newStr;
}
const p = document.createElement("p")
replaceDOM(string, "Dog", p);
```

Comment: Please approve my answer, if that was the one you were looking for.